# Set file path in <s:file> in Struts2 while open for edit mode

Tags: file, file-upload, struts2, struts

I have one file upload field in my struts2 form like:

`<s:file label="Upload" name="file" id="file" size="40" cssClass="width284" value="%{file}"/>`

this work perfectly for upload file, now when i `open this form again in edit mode` to edit information `i got this file field empty` i.e. file name (with path) not found in file browser text box. I have getter/setter method for the file object and i have set file in the pojo object which i get as result.

I have also set value in file tag, still not getting file name in text box of the file tag.

I dont know how this happend any one know about this.
Thanks in advanced.

**EDITED**
My JSP file :-

```
<form name="library" id="library" method="post" action="addlibrary" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div><s:textfield name="title" value="%{title}" id="title" label="Title" cssClass="width284"/><span class="red">*</span><div>
<div><s:file label="Upload" name="file" id="file" size="40" cssClass="width284" value="%{file}" /></div>
<div><span class="submit" ><s:submit name="submit" value="Add to Library" cssStyle="width:130px;"></s:submit></span> </div>
```

My action class code while open for edit :-

```
private File file;
private String fileContentType;
private String fileFileName;    

public String edit() {
    if (this.object.getId() == 0) {
        this.object = null;
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        this.object = this.objectDAO.getobjectContent(this.object.getId());
        String filePath = "d:\\myProject\\Documents\\"+ this.object.getFileName();
        this.file = new File(filePath);
        return INPUT;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the relevant part of the code

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I have added some code...

Comment: `file` is of type `File` while name attribute of the file tag is of type string and i am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve? can you explain it more

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi when i open this form again for edit a particular record than i got my file name for that record display in file text box.

Comment: I believe setting the path of a file input is prohibited for security
reasons.though i am not like 100% sure as i have read it somewhere,

Comment: That's correct; you cannot set a name in a file only.

Comment: Yep, that is done for security reasons.